# Sharepoint 2013/PowerShell : Error on item list update with batch

Tags: xml, powershell, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to synchronize a list item using a batch from a first site to another site (SharePoint 2013).
I tried the PowerShell code (available down below) with 3 list item.
The first one did work but the other 2 didn't.
So looking the code below, where would the problem come from ?

So this is the code :

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetname = "ImportFromFiles", SupportsShouldProcess = $True, ConfirmImpact = 'Medium')]
param(
    # Variation
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet("en-us", "fr-fr", "es-es")]
    [string]$Variation,

    # Logs directory path
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$LogsPath = "Logs",

    # Data directory path
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$DataPath = "Data",

    # Batch directory path
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$BatchUpdatesPath = "BatchUpdates"
)

if (-not $ExportToCSV) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$logsPath = "$PSScriptRoot\$LogsPath"
$dataPath = "$PSScriptRoot\$DataPath"
$batchUpdatesPath = "$PSScriptRoot\$BatchUpdatesPath"

if (!(Test-Path $logsPath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $logsPath
}

if (!(Test-Path $dataPath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $dataPath
}

if (!(Test-Path $batchUpdatesPath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $batchUpdatesPath
}

function Update-ExistingItems {
    param ()

    if (-not $ExportToCSV) {
        $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "contoso.com/$Variation"
        $publicItemsList = $web.Lists['Items']
    }

    $methodBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

    $batchFormat = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:Batch OnError="Continue">{0}</ows:Batch>'

    $ItemsCSV = Import-Csv "$dataPath\Items-Fields.csv" -Encoding Default
    $PublicItemsCSV = Import-Csv "$dataPath\Public-Items-Fields-$Variation.csv" -Encoding Default

    $Items = @{ }
    $PublicItems = @{ }

    $PublicItemsCSV | ForEach-Object { $PublicItems[[int]$_.SourceId] = $_ }
    $ItemsCSV | ForEach-Object { $Items[[int]$_.ID] = $_ }

    $hashFields = @{
        'Item Name'           = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_Name'; displayName = 'Item Name' };
        'Item Address 1'      = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_Address_x0020_1'; displayName = 'Item Address 1' };
        'Item Address 2'      = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_Address_x0020_2'; displayName = 'Item Address 2' };
        'Item City'           = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_City'; displayName = 'Item City' };
        'Item Principal Name' = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_Principal_x0020_Nam'; displayName = 'Item Principal Name' };
        'Item Phone'          = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_Phone'; displayName = 'Item Phone' };
        'Item Fax'            = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_Fax'; displayName = 'Item Fax' };
        'Item status'         = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_status'; displayName = 'Item status' };
        'Item Email'          = @{internalName = 'Item_x0020_E_x002d_mail'; displayName = 'Item Email' };
    }

    $PublicItems.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        $methodFormat = '<Method>'
        $methodFormat += '<SetList Scope="Request">{0}</SetList>'
        $methodFormat += '<SetVar Name="Cmd">Save</SetVar>'
        $methodFormat += '<SetVar Name="ID">{1}</SetVar>'
        $script:updateItem = $false
        $itemID = $_

        if (-not $Items[$itemID]) {
            return
        }

        $hashFields.Keys | ForEach-Object {
            if ($Items[$itemID].$_ -ne $PublicItems[$itemID].$_) {
                $script:updateItem = $true
                Write-Output "$($itemID): $_ => $($Items[$itemID].$_) not equal $($PublicItems[$itemID].$_)"
                $methodFormat += '<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#' + $hashFields[$_]['internalName'] + '">' + $Items[$itemID].$_ + '</SetVar>'
            }
        }

        $itemTypeOfGuid = $Items[$itemID].'bd17fb3aa4bd4111aef976748382c614'.split('|')[1]
        $publicItemTypeOfGuid = $PublicItems[$itemID].'d3fd19dcbce247fbbae29f662eba929c'.split('|')[1]
        $itemTypeOfWssId = +$Items[$itemID].'Item Type of'.split(';')[0]

        $hash = @{
            205 = @{WssId = 3; "fr-fr" = "Secondaire"; "en-us" = "Secondary"; "es-es" = "Secundaria" };
            210 = @{WssId = 14; "fr-fr" = "Pré-primaire"; "en-us" = "Pre-primary"; "es-es" = "Pre-primaria" };
            274 = @{WssId = 242; "fr-fr" = "Pré-primaire/Primaire"; "en-us" = "Pre-Primary/Primary"; "es-es" = "Pre-primaria/Primaria" };
            204 = @{WssId = 2; "fr-fr" = "Primaire"; "en-us" = "Primary"; "es-es" = "Primaria" };
            209 = @{WssId = 11; "fr-fr" = "Primaire/secondaire"; "en-us" = "Primary/Secondary"; "es-es" = "Primaria/Secundaria" };
            273 = @{WssId = 241; "fr-fr" = "Du primaire au secondaire"; "en-us" = "Pre-primary to Secondary"; "es-es" = "Pre-primaria hasta secundaria" };
            208 = @{WssId = 8; "fr-fr" = "Établissement de formation des enseignants"; "en-us" = "Teacher Training Institution"; "es-es" = "Institución de formación docente" };
            207 = @{WssId = 7; "fr-fr" = "Établissement technique professionnel"; "en-us" = "Vocational and Technical Institution"; "es-es" = "Institución profesional y técnica" };
            272 = @{WssId = 240; "fr-fr" = "Centre d’enseignement non formel"; "en-us" = "Non-Formal Education Center"; "es-es" = "Centro de educación no formal" };
        }

        $typeOf = "$($hash[+$itemTypeOfWssId]["WssId"])" + ";#" + $hash[+$itemTypeOfWssId][$Variation] + "|" + $itemTypeOfGuid

        if ($itemTypeOfGuid -ne $publicItemTypeOfGuid) {
            $script:updateItem = $true
            $methodFormat += '<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Item_x0020_Type_x0020_of_x00200">' + $typeOf + '</SetVar>'
        }

        $methodFormat += '</Method>'

        if ([System.Convert]::ToBoolean($script:updateItem)) {
            if (-not $ExportToCSV) {
                $methodBuilder.AppendFormat($methodFormat, $publicItemsList.ID.ToString(), $PublicItems[$itemID].ID) | Out-Null
            }
            else {
                $methodBuilder.AppendFormat($methodFormat, 'Items', $PublicItems[$itemID].ID) | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }

    $batch = [string]::Format($batchFormat, $methodBuilder.ToString())

    if (-not $ExportToCSV) {
        $batchReturn = $web.ProcessBatchData($batch)
        $batchReturn
    }
}
```

This is the batch i get with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:Batch OnError="Continue">
    <Method>
        <SetList Scope="Request">b9b3794a-8bd1-4e13-8746-508dbc80d504</SetList>
        <SetVar Name="Cmd">Save</SetVar><SetVar Name="ID">94388</SetVar>
        <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Item_x0020_E_x002d_mail">email@email.com</SetVar>
        <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Item_x0020_Phone">33612345789</SetVar>
        <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Item_x0020_Fax"></SetVar>
        <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Item_x0020_Type_x0020_of_x00200">
            2;#Primary|548d9217-b7cf-4714-95ac-7f3de20ee0df
        </SetVar>
    </Method>
</ows:Batch>
```

and this is the error I get with the second and third synchronization :

```
<Results><Result ID="" Code="-2147467259">
<ErrorText>Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.</ErrorText></Result>
</Results>
```

Comment: You're posting 135 lines of code, asking *"where could the problem come from?"* - That's really hard to say. Can you post something in the order of 13 lines of code that reproduce the problem you see, and cut out everything that is not related?

Comment: Sorry for uploading that long code.
For more details, all the process is working during batch construction.
I get this error precisely when i launch the `$web.ProcessBatchData($batch)` code. Whichever column I modify, whichever item I modify, only the first item succeed and not the others.